# Linq for nested property

Tags: c#, linq

Below is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Data xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <DataContainer xsi:type="ClassA">
    <Identifier></Identifier>
    <prop2></prop2>
    <prop3></prop3>
    <Key>549</Key>
  </DataContainer>
  <DataContainer xsi:type="ClassB">
    <Identifier></Identifier>
    <prop2></prop2>
    <prop3></prop3>
    <ClassC>
      <ClassD>
        <Identifier></Identifier>
        <prop2></prop2>
        <prop3></prop3>
        <Key>461</Key>
      </ClassD>
       <ClassD>
        <Identifier></Identifier>
        <prop2></prop2>
        <prop3></prop3>
        <Key>468</Key>
      </ClassD>
       <ClassD>
        <Identifier></Identifier>
        <prop2></prop2>
        <prop3></prop3>
        <Key>460</Key>
      </ClassD>
    </ClassC>
    <ClassE>
      <ClassF>
        <Identifier></Identifier>
        <prop2></prop2>
        <prop3></prop3>
        <Key>549</Key>
      </ClassF>
    </ClassE>
  </DataContainer>
..
..
..
.. Some more class that may or may not contain Key property
</Data>
```

I know its complicated xml structure but that how it is, sorry. I have to get the value of Identifier property based on Key property value, like where Key=549 or whatever. I Know i can do

```
Data.OfType<ClassA>().where(h=>h.Key==someValue).Select(...
```

But do i have to do this for each different class type as Key property is in different classes? Besides this, if in future another class came in and i have to find the identifier based on that class do i have to add another linq query to find that identifier? Is there any better solution for this or i am stuck with individual query for each class type?

I already have 'Data' deserialized object which Exactly looks like and Based upon above xml & i am looking for a way that gives me the 'identifier' property value based on Key..

Help will be appreciated,

Comment: What is `Data` in your sample code, is that already deserialized from the XML document?

Comment: yes Data is already deserialized

Comment: Your question has a block of XML and asks about getting a nested property... and then you say that the data is already deserialized.  This makes your question very confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily do it with Linq-to-XML like this:-

```
 XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("YourXML");
 IEnumerable<string> Identifiers = xdoc.Root.Elements("DataContainer")
                                       .Where(x => (string)x.Element("Key") == "549")
                                       .Select(x => (string)x.Element("Identifier"));
```

Comment: is there any other way without using xdoc? Sorry

Comment: i already have deserialized object that's why i cant really use xDoc

Comment: @Angloos - But you never mentioned that and started question with the XML as if it was not parsed. So now you have `List<T>`? What is the issue then?

Comment: issue is i don't know how to get identifier? Sorry again if i haven't made it enough clear

Comment: Once the XML has been deserialized, then your only option is a generic function that is based off of the sample code your provided in your question.

Comment: @Angloos - In that case show your `Data` object and tell specifically where you are stuck.

Comment: @RahulSingh my Data object is exactly based on this xml structure : )

Comment: @CodingGorilla yeah that's what i was thinking my self but i wasn't sure if Linq will help me here .. thanks

Comment: @Angloos - Yes CodingGorilla is correct you can use a generic function in that case. Anyways one suggestion if you use `LINQ-to-XML` like this you can fetch the `Identifiers` directly based on class name & key.

Answer (score 0):

Based off of the comments from Rahul's answer, you might consider something like this:

```
public class DataBase
{
   public string Identifier { get; set; }
   public string Key { get; set; } 
}

public IEnumerable<DataBase> FindInstancesByKey(IEnumerable<DataBase> data, string key)
{
   return data.Where(d => d.Key == key);
}

public void Main()
{
   // Deserialize the data
   var data = Deserialize();

   var instances = FindInstancesByKey(data, "mykey");
   Console.WriteLine(instances.Select(x => x.Instance);
}
```

Creating a base class that all your XML instances inherit from gives you the strongly typed set up you need in order to start querying against the `Instance` and `Key` properties generically.

Comment: i think this require change in my classes structure? if not, am i missing something?

Comment: @Angloos You are correct, it would require some changes to your class hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

To get all keyElements with closest Identifier value you can use the following:
//Key allows to search for all keys in the XML & ../Identifier allows to find closest sibling to the key.

```
        var xDoc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\temp\test.xml");
        var keyElements = xDoc.XPathSelectElements("//Key").ToList();
        var items = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
        foreach (var keyElement in keyElements)
        {
            var identifier = keyElement.XPathSelectElement("../Identifier");

            items.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(keyElement.Value, (identifier != null ? identifier.Value : null)));
        }
```